# Two way automatic model creation for django OneToOneField

Tags: python, django, one-to-one

Let's say I have the following class to extend the built-in django User class using a OneToOneField:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    django_user = models.OneToOneField(User, unique=True)
    extra1 = models.CharField()
    extra1 = models.CharField()
       ...
```

My problem is:

- I would like UserProfile to be created whenever a User is created
- AND vice versa: when a UserProfile is created I would like to automatically add a new (django) User (a username is autogenerated in that case)
- Additionally I would like to sync 3 fields from the standard User class with my model (email, first_name and last_name), so updates are part of the problem as well.

I have successfully used a post_save signal to achieve this in a **one-way** fashion, but doing it both ways seems difficult (registering a post_save for both User and UserProfile seems a bad idea)

Has anyone done something like this? Any help is much appreciated

Using a custom User model is (unfortunately) not an option because it isn't supported by other apps that I use.

Comment: the `post_save` is all you need, because when you are creating the `UserProfile` object, there is __no__ way you can create a profile without the django `User` object, so you are covered there. The other thing. `userprofile.django_user.email` gives you the `email`. Why do you want to create redundancy there?

Comment: Good point, I really don't like the redundancy. However django-cms  currently doesn't support custom User classes. I thought of this approach to allow a smooth transition to a custom User (in which case User and UserProfile are basically merged into one class)

Comment: Well, in that case, have the inheritance model `class UserProfile(User)` - This way, the transition would be simpler (am i missing something ?)

Comment: @karthikr Using a custom User model is supported in Django 1.5+ and should not be done that way, but by inheriting from `AbstractBaseUser`. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/auth/customizing/#auth-custom-user

Comment: @StevenB Really, ask yourself if you really want this. Creating a user profile with redundancy and manual syncing... that is a big pain. Instead, ask what you are trying to achieve in the first place. I sincerely hope there's a better solution to your issue.

Comment: what version of django are you using?